# Where condition as varchar using variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, where-clause, dynamic-sql

I have a SQL query in varchar like below:

```
declare @dataSourceId varchar(500) = ''
declare @SQL varchar(500) = 'select * from DataSources
                             where Data is not null 
                               and DataSourceId not in ('+@dataSourceId+')
                                or Data is not null 
                               and DataSourceId is not null'
```

If `@dataSourceId` is empty string `''` then I would like to execute condition `Data is not null and DataSourceId is not null` but if `@dataSourceId` is not `''` then execute first condition. How can I implement this solution?

Comment: What could `@dataSourceId` contain, e.g. a list of values like `'7,13,42'`? How about executable code like `select FooId from Bar`? There's a big difference in how to handle them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can programmatically build the conditions like so:

```
declare @dataSourceId varchar(500) = ''
declare @SQL varchar(500) = 
    'select * from datasources where data is not null and '
    + case 
        when @dataSourceId <> '' then 'datasourceid in (' + @dataSourceId + ')'
        else 'datasource is not null'
    end
```

Comment: This, however, is likely **dangerously** open to injection attacks and is *far* from recommended.

Answer (score 3):

What you should *really* be doing here is **not** injecting values into your statement; that path leads to SQL injection. Properly parametrise your statements.

If you *must* pass a delimited list, use a string splitter. I *assume* you are using a recent version of SQL Server (if not, you'll need to use a user defined string splitter, such as an XML splitter for `delimitedsplit8k_LEAD`).

```sql
SELECT *
FROM dbo.DataSources
WHERE (Data IS NOT NULL 
  AND DataSourceId not in (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@dataSourceId,',')))
   OR (NULLIF(@dataSourceId,'') IS NULL
  AND  Data IS NOT NULL
  AND  DataSourceId IS NOT NULL)
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

Of course, this might not perform too well, due to the `OR` make up, so you could use a **properly** parametrised dynamic statement instead:

```sql
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

SET @SQL = N'SELECT *' + @CRLF +    
           N'FROM dbo.DataSources' + @CRLF + 
           N'WHERE Data IS NOT NULL' + @CRLF +
           CASE WHEN NULLIF(@dataSourceId,'') IS NULL THEN N'  AND DataSourceId IS NOT NULL'
                                                      ELSE N'  AND DataSourceId NOT IN(SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@dataSourceId,'','')'
           END + N';'
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@dataSourceId varchar(500)', @dataSourceId;
```